# problem starting project in google web toolkit eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, gwt, plugins

am new to the google webtoolkit for eclipse. After successivefully installing the GWT plugin for eclipse and start my first project i got an error "`invocation of com.google.gwt.user.tools.WebAppCreator failed, See the error log for more details`". Anyone who knows the solution can help. thanks.

Here is the error log;

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.ui 4 10001 2011-03-08 11:47:54.258
!MESSAGE Internal Error
!STACK 1
Java Model Exception: Core Exception [code 0] Invocation of com.google.gwt.user.tools.WebAppCreator failed. See the error log for more details.
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1975)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:4777)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.actions.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Invocation of com.google.gwt.user.tools.WebAppCreator failed. See the error log for more details.
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.runtime.tools.WebAppProjectCreatorRunner.createProject(WebAppProjectCreatorRunner.java:53)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.wizards.WebAppProjectCreator.createGWTProject(WebAppProjectCreator.java:549)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.wizards.WebAppProjectCreator.create(WebAppProjectCreator.java:297)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.wizards.NewWebAppProjectWizard.finishPage(NewWebAppProjectWizard.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.NewElementWizard$2.run(NewElementWizard.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1975)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:4777)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.actions.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
!SUBENTRY 1 com.google.gwt.eclipse.core 4 0 2011-03-08 11:47:54.259
!MESSAGE Invocation of com.google.gwt.user.tools.WebAppCreator failed. See the error log for more details.
```

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by changing workspace. Permissions on the old workspace directory were fine, I still dunno what was wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

Unchecking the "Generate project sample code" checkbox on the "New web Application Project" window solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the metadata folder from you existing work space and restart eclipse.  It is a hidden folder for me `OS=Ubuntu-12.04`. `Ctrl+h` to show.

Comment: oh, and then import existing project folders back in. forgot that part

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured GWT SDK in your project?

Comment: yes, i did configure it. Actually i found the problem and it was that i the workspace or project folder had readonly permissions! My Mistake, thanks though for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Deselecting "Use Google Web Toolkit" is the solution for me. May be my google web toolkit (GWT) installation has some problems.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the following steps to get this resolved:
1. go to control panel > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables
2. Remove classpath from both user variables as well as from the system variables.

I hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by unchecking "Generate project sample code" checkbox on the "New web Application Project" window